# Como guardar los datos de un select con laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

la cosa es que estoy realizando un proyecto de digitalizacion de datos, el cual lleva 3 selects para seleccionar una area, una categoria y una subcategoria, ya tengo los selects dinamicos y todo, pero yo lo agregue a un form de laravel como se muestra a continuacion

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre del documento') }}
    {{ Form::text ('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('image', 'Imagen') }}
    {{ Form::file ('image') }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('entry_date', 'Fecha de ingreso') }}
    {{ Form::date('entry_date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'date', 'style' => 'width: 180px; margin-bottom: 30px;']) }}
</div>

<select id="areas" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
  <option value="area">seleccione el area</option>
</select>


<select id="categorias" class="form-control" style="width: 220px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
  <option value="categoria">selecccione la categoria</option>
</select>


<select id="subCategorias" class="form-control" style="width: 240px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
  <option value="subcategoria">selecccione la subcategoria</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('comment', 'Comentario') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('comment', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
    <a style= "color: white;" type="submit"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{ route('documents.index') }}">
        Cancelar
    </a>
</div>
```

Y a la hora de guardarlo no se como guardar los datos de dicho select.

A continuacion muestro el metodo store para guardar los datos:

```
public function store(DocumentStoreRequest $request)
    {

        $document = Document::create($request->all());

        //Image
        if($request->file('image')){

            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('img', $request->file('image'));
            $document->fill(['image' => asset($path)])->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('documents.index', $document->id)
            ->with('info', 'Documento creado con exito');
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, a mí no me queda muy claro, hablas de guardar los datos de la select> pero hay unos 3 en el html (cuál) luego en el código guardas un documento, no sé con qué tienes el problema.

Comment: Buenas, mi problema es que necesito guardar los datos de los 3 selects en la base de datos, y no se como plantearlo en el metodo store, este metodo es para guardar los datos de un documento, los datos se recogen con el formulario donde se encuentran los selects

Comment: el método `create` espera que los datos que le pasas ( en este caso 
 `$request->all()` ) correspondan con la estructura del modelo ( en este caso `Document`). Podrías agregar a la pregunta el código del Modelo `Document` y la estructura de `$request->all()`?